# What kind of i-mutation is PG mahtiz OE meaht?

Tags: mutation

What kind of i-mutation is PG mahtiz OE meaht?

I don't see it (a ~ ea) in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut#I-mutation_in_Old_English) table.

Comment: Off the top of my head (so take with a grain of salt), I think those are different words. PG has both _*mahtiz_ and _*mahtuz_ (i.e., both an i-stem and a u-stem), and I would guess the i-stem is behind OE _miht_, while the u-stem yielded _meaht_, so there is no i-mutation at all, just breaking.